# Nuxt.js: error 404 to resourcer under _nuxt/*

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm creating my gh-pages using nuxt.js. But after deploy, some of nuxt.js requests are receiving 404 responses and I have no idea how to fix it.

Here is my [github.io page](https://getjv.github.io/portfolio/). Under `npm run dev` environment it works but after deploy did not.

[image]

Comment: I  have the same problem. Any solutions found?

Comment: no. I rolled back to regular vue.